# windows phone emulator not displayed , showing error 0x80131500

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

during debugging, it is showing error no 0x80131500 in deploying. 
Emulator is not displayed.

i m using windows 8.1 pro
,visual studio 2012  n 
windows phone sdk

Answer (score 0):

There are several [posted here in the community](https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20windows%208.1%20windows%20phone%20emulator%20error%20code%200x80131500&go=Search&qs=n&sp=-1&pq=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20windows%208.1%20windows%20phone%20emulator%20error%20code%200x80131500&sc=0-77&sk=&cvid=9484427A46AF470E99F77EF088705593&first=1&FORM=PERE) about this issue.

Please be sure to have the Update 4 for the VS2012.